# SMS not being sent on mobile phone using bulk sms site

Tags: java, http-headers, connection, sms-gateway

I am trying to send the sms on mobile through the bulk sms sending site . I am trying to send the sms through java api by using the following code. its not showing any error but message is not being sent.

```
 String urlParameters="usr=username &pwd=1234 &ph=9015569447 &text=Hello";
 //String request = "http://hapi.smsapi.org/SendSMS.aspx?";
 String request="http://WWW.BULKSMS.FELIXINDIA.COM/send.php?";
try{                        
URL url = new URL(request); 
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 


connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +         Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
  connection.setUseCaches (false);

DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);

    wr.flush();
wr.close();
connection.disconnect();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 System.out.print(ex);
}
```

Comment: Why do you always print `"message not sent"`?

Comment: its just a message to check its not throws exception nothing else

Comment: Then it should say "message sent", isn't it? Or even better "message sending finished"

Comment: What are connection.getResponseCode()  and connection.getResponseMessage() saying? Have you tried to send a message using another way, for instance a browser?

Comment: what error message it says , i m guessing the web sites are barred to send bulk messages in INDIA , does it have something to do with this , take a look

Comment: exception isjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected and shows the response code 200

Comment: not get the answer yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the response code after writing to the stream to be able to tell what's going on:

```
int rc = connection.getResponseCode();
if(rc==200)
{
    //no http response code error
    //read the result from the server
    rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    //get the returned data too
    returnString=sb.toString();
}
else
{
    System.out.println("http response code error: "+rc+"\n");
}
```

(Code pasted from [here](http://www.java-forums.org/networking/60379-httpurlconnection-post-data.html))

Also **NEVER** do this:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.out.print(ex);
}
```

This is bad for your health: the next one debugging your code will slap you with a hard and heavy object finding this!

Either

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

or

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    LOG.error("Something went wrong (adequate error message here please)", ex);
}
```

**MUST** be done!!!

Comment: +1 for the comment on exception handling and the heavy object :)

Comment: exception isjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected and shows the response code 200 –

Answer (score 1):

I see some space between request parameters URL :

```
 String urlParameters="usr=username&pwd=1234&ph=9015569447&text=Hello";
```

This might be the issue.

Comment: Didn't spot them, nice finding!